# C++ compile error when includeing Irrlicht static lib

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, x11, irrlicht

U have a compile error when trying to include the Irrlicht static libraries into my cmake project

Compile error:

```
max@max-MS-7369:~/Desktop/survival/build$ make Scanning dependencies   of target survival
[ 33%] Building CXX object    src/CMakeFiles/survival.dir/technic.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object   src/CMakeFiles/survival.dir/render.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object    src/CMakeFiles/survival.dir/survival.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable    ../debug/survival
/usr/bin/ld:    ../../irrlicht/lib/Linux/libIrrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceLinux.o): undefined   reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'
/usr/bin/ld: note:    'XConvertSelection' is defined in DSO    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so  so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [debug/survival] Error 1
make[1]: ***    [src/CMakeFiles/survival.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
max@max-MS-7369:~/Desktop/survival/build$
```

And this is how I try to include the lib:

```
# find dependencies for irrlicht
FIND_PACKAGE(ZLIB)
FIND_PACKAGE(X11)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL)
# includes
set( survival_CUSTOM_INCLUDES
    ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${X11_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${survival_SOURCE_DIR}/irrlicht/include
    )
# libraries
set( survival_CUSTOM_LIBRARIES
    ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
    ${X11_LIBRARIES}
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    ${survival_SOURCE_DIR}/irrlicht/lib/Linux/libIrrlicht.a
    )
```

I don't get why it says it cant find `XConvertSelection` even though I have included the X11 lib.

Answer (score 4):

i added those 2 libs to fix it

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1
```

they werent included by the libs given from FIND_PACKAGE()